# How to visualize only specific geographic area with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr, visualization

I'm working with ggplot2 and i'm creating a geographic representation of my country.
This is the dataset and the script I'm using ( prov2022 is the shapefile for the map)

```
#dataset
COD_REG   COD_PROV   Wage
1         91         530
1         92         520
1         93         510
2         97         500
2         98         505
2         99         501
13        102        700
13        103        800   
13        159        900
18        162        740
18        123        590   
18        119        420
19        162        340
19        123        290   
19        119        120
```

```
#script
right_join(prov2022, dataset, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `Wage`)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'black'))
```

It works fine, but now I'm insterested in visualizing  only a specific area.
If I add a filter to select the regions that have the value of the variable COD_REG > 13, I get what I was looking for but the color gradient changes.

```
right_join(prov2022, dataset, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  filter(COD_REG >= 13 ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = `Wage`)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'black'))
```

The color gradient of the output that I get is different if I use the filter because the colors are applied considering only the values of that specific areas and not anymore the ones of the whole country.
As consequence these areas do not have anymore the colors that they had at the beggining ( I mean in the entire map that i get with the first script).
I need to maintain the color gradient of the whole country,  but get as output of ggplot2 only some specific areas without changing anything.
How do I solve?

Comment: `Error: object 'prov2022' not found` (same for `dataset`). Not having any data or even knowing what it looks like (besides inferring some column names from your code) ... nor seeing the gradients change ... not a lot to help you with.

Comment: @r2evans you are absolutely right! I've edited the question... it should be complete now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I'll use fake data on the `state` map from package `maps`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
usa <- sf::st_as_sf(map('state', plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
set.seed(42)
usa$val <- runif(length(usa$ID))
ggplot(usa, aes(fill = val)) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'black'))
```

[image: states, baseline colors]

If we naively just filter the states we want to see, the colors change:

```r
ggplot(usa, aes(fill = val)) +
  geom_sf(data = ~ subset(., val > 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'black'))
```

[image: filtered states, relative colors changed]

If we add `geom_blank`, though, we can normalize the range of values from which the scale is determined. Since it still uses all of the original data, and it does nothing with it (except to update scales and limits), it "costs" nothing as far as drawing (e.g.) transparent or super-small things in order to get its way. From `?geom_blank`:

```
     The blank geom draws nothing, but can be a useful way of ensuring
     common scales between different plots. See 'expand_limits()' for
     more details.
```

Code:

```r
ggplot(usa, aes(fill = val)) +
  geom_sf(data = ~ subset(., val > 0.5)) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'black')) + 
  geom_blank()
```

[image: filtered states, colors same as the]

Notice that I'm using inline `~` rlang-style functions for subsetting the data; this is my convention but is not required.

Comment: When I first discovered (read about) `geom_blank`, sooooooo many things became easier, more elegant, faster, less hacky, etc. There are certainly other tricks to use to get the same effect, but I find this introduces the least unreadable-code, the least processing (since rendering complex plots "takes time"), and often (but not always) the most compatibility with downstream processing (e.g., `svg`, `plotly`). Glad it worked!