# How to subset with ggplot2 without removing the shapes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, subset, visualization

Hy guys, I'm working with ggplot2 and creating a geographic representation of my country. This is the dataset and the script I'm using ( *prov2022* is the shapefile for the map)

```
#database
COD_REG   COD_PROV   Wage
1         91         530
1         92         520
1         93         410
2         97         300
2         98         205
2         99         501
13        102        700
13        103        800   
13        159        900
18        162        740
18        123        590   
18        119        420
19        162        340
19        123        290   
19        119        120
```

```
#script
right_join(prov2022, database, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `Wage`))+
  geom_sf(data = ~ subset(., `Wage` > 300 & `Wage` <= 800)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow' , 'red', 'black')) +
  geom_blank()
```

It works fine, but I'm insterested in visualizing also the shapes of the areas that I've exclude with the command *subset*. My purpose was to fill with the color gradient only the regions with `Wage` > 300 & `Wage` <= 800, but setting *geom_sf(data = ~ subset(., `Wage` > 300 & `Wage` <= 800))* I have removed completely the ones that do not satisfy this condition from my map. Actually, I need to have them in the output but whitout being filled (just their shapes).

How do I solve?

**UPDATE ABOUT SCRIPT**
This is what I'm using after @r2evans' suggestion

```
right_join(prov2022, database, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `Importo medio mensile`))+
  geom_sf(data = ~ transform(., `Importo medio mensile` = ifelse(`Importo medio mensile` > 1500 & `Importo medio mensile` <= 1700, `Importo medio mensile`[NA], `Importo medio mensile`))) + 
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'black'), na.value = "#00000000") +
  geom_blank()
```

but the answer is

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Importo medio mensile' not found
```

**UPDATE PART 2**

If I want to fill using another variable *Salario reale*, but I want to maintaining the selection of the areas done with the values of the previous variable *Importo medio mensile*, what should I do?

Substituting only the fill variable doesn't work

```
right_join(prov2022, database, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `Salario Reale`))+
  geom_sf(data = ~ dplyr::mutate(., `Importo medio mensile` = ifelse(`Importo medio mensile` > 1500 & `Importo medio mensile` <= 1700, `Importo medio mensile`, `Importo medio mensile`[NA]))) + 
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'black'), na.value = "#00000000") +
  geom_blank()
```

it colors all the regions of my country as if the subset that I want to maintain (the one with the variable Importo medio mensile) weren't there. How can I solve?

**UPDATE 3**
The solution proposed by r2evans works!!

Comment: Hi @io_boh, could you provide a fully reproducible example (maybe using the `nc` shapefile that ships with sf)?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a step before ggplot like `mutate(Wage = if_else(between(Wage, 300, 800), Wage, NA_real_)) %>% ` so that Wages outside that range are NA and given a different fill. (by default `na.value` is "grey50")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filtering out the data, just replace (optionally inline) the not-to-be-colored values with `NA`.

Continuing from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75338586/3358272),

```r
ggplot(usa, aes(fill = val)) +
  geom_sf(data = ~ transform(., val = ifelse(val < 0.5, val[NA], val))) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'black')) + 
  geom_blank()
```

[image: ggplot2 with other regions values replaced with NA]

(The use of `val[NA]` is to make sure we have the one specific class of `NA`, as there are at least 6 different *types* of `NA`.)

Granted, gray may not be what you want, so you can fix that with `na.value=` (its default is `na.value="grey50"`).

```r
ggplot(usa, aes(fill = val)) +
  geom_sf(data = ~ transform(., val = ifelse(val < 0.5, val[NA], val))) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'black'), 
                       na.value = "#00000000") + 
  geom_blank()
```

[image: same image but with non-colored states now with transparent color]

where `#00000000` is a fully-transparent color. The first six `0`s don't matter, the trailing two `00` indicates an alpha of 0 (transparent).

---

I *think* this means you want something like this:

```r
right_join(prov2022, database, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `Importo medio mensile`))+
  geom_sf(data = ~ mutate(., `Importo medio mensile` = ifelse(`Importo medio mensile` > 300 & `Importo medio mensile` <= 800, `Importo medio mensile`, `Importo medio mensile`[NA]))) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow' , 'red', 'black')) +
  geom_blank()
```

Notes:

- I updated from `` `Wage` `` in your example to `` `Importo medio mensile` `` as you mentioned in your comments;
- My code above uses `transform`, which is base R and in general works fine, *except* when the names being used are "not normal R names", in which case it tends to add `.`s to the name. The use of `dplyr::mutate` fixes this problem. You're already using `right_join`, so I think I'm not adding any dependency.

Another way to look at this: the `data = ~ mutate(...)` is changing the data internally-only, so that the original data is untouched. One could easily do something like this for the same effect.

```r
right_join(prov2022, database, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  mutate(SOMETHING = ifelse(`Importo medio mensile` > 300 & `Importo medio mensile` <= 800, `Importo medio mensile`, `Importo medio mensile`[NA])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = SOMETHING)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( 'white', 'yellow' , 'red', 'black')) +
  geom_blank(aes(fill = `Importo medio mensile`))
```

noting that we needed to redefine `fill=` in the blank geom so that the correct range of values would be processed by ggplot.

Comment: thank you another time! substituting my variable, I get this answer from R:<< Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Wage' not found ...

Comment: Not sure. Is there a reason you're using backticks around it? It's a simple-enough symbol, typically backticks are only required if the name is not a normal R name (e.g., starts with a number or includes spaces or special characters).

Comment: Probably this is the reason! Actually, the name of my variable is not Wage, but It is Importo medio mensile ( which means "monthly average wage" in my native language ). Therefore I have included it in my script using  backticks around it until now and it worked! This is the way how I'm using it:  `Importo medio mensile`.... How can I solve??

Comment: Okay, then yes backticks are required (due to the spaces).

Comment: Try this? `geom_sf(data = ~ transform(., \`Importo medio mensile\` = ifelse(\`Importo medio mensile\` > 300 & \`Importo medio mensile\` <= 800, \`Importo medio mensile\`, \`Importo medio mensile\`[NA])))`

Comment: I see the error, stby ... the issue is because `transform` is adding dots to the name (since it's not a normally-legal R name). Since you're using `dplyr` elsewhere, replace `transform` with `dplyr::mutate` and it should work.

Comment: See the updated code ... `mutate` fixes it.

Comment: I'm really really sorry about that. I didn't even know that ! I didn't know that I have to accept an answer... Believe me, I'm sorry, it wasn't my intention to take advantage of your time... i'm going to read the links you provide me and find out how to do that! Sorry another time

Comment: I appreciate you responding so quickly. I find (anecdotally) that many new users don't get that from the tour (if they even do the tour \*shrug\*), so it's not uncommon, but Stack staff/moderators seem to think that the tour is sufficient to communicate so many things to new users, when (in my experience, at least) new users are usually so busy or in a rush that they easily skip over things like this. It's often a "trickle-effort" to internalize the ethos of each forum, as they all different (sometimes substantially). Thanks again!

Comment: yes, i'm sorry, it is my first time that I use a forum and I didn't have any idea how it works.... I didn't realize that there was a guide to read before. Thanks for having explained me how to use the forum properly ( hoping that I've accepted the answers in the right way), because your explanantions will be helpful for other people. And thank for you R knowledge, without you it would have been impossible to me to solve it

Comment: if you have time I need one of your R trick to solve a new problem.... I've posted it in the answer

Comment: Did my comment in the (now-deleted) answer work for you?

Comment: I've deleted it and write it as an update of my answer.... I hope now it is explained better what i'm looking for, maybe in the previous answer it wasn't clear

Comment: maybe I didn't understand it. You have suggested <<you need to also change the references inside the data=~mutate(...).) >>, but actually I need to maintain the same values of variable  "Importo medio mensile" to select the regions... I just need to fill these regions with another variable

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Try `geom_sf(data=~mutate(., \`Salario Reale\` = ifelse(\`Importo medio mensile\` > 1500 & \`Importo medio mensile\` <= 1700, \`Salario Reale\`, \`Salario Reale\`[NA])))`